# PHPMailer - make the sender mail variable

Tags: php, email, sendmail, phpmailer

I'm using php mailer and i cant specify the sender mail , i want to be a variable every one type his email to be here , but it cant be done i must type my email and my password , so anyone know how it can be done

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
// 1 = errors and messages
// 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "usermail";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->addReply=$_POST['email'] ;
$mail->addAddress=$_POST['email'];
$mail->Subject=$_POST['subject'];
$mail->Body=$_POST['message'] .$_POST['email'];
$mail->Sender=$_POST['email'];
```

Comment: do you want to specify the sender mail?

Comment: They wont be typing their username and password on your page for their google accounts would they? If they wont, you cant just use their email address and provide your password. Wont authenticate

Comment: @Shahbaz $mail->Sender=$_POST['email']; this way ?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky i tried this before and when i make it this shows up " Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed."

Comment: @OmarMokhtar you can also use $mail->From = 'sender mail address'; $mail->FromName = 'sender name';

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("example@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");
@$mail->Send()
```

Answer (score -5):

**Go through this link -> [Own-Email-System-using-SMTP-and-PHPMailer](https://github.com/pradipkumarraushan/Own-Email-System-using-SMTP-and-PHPMailer)**
OR,
   Please elaborate your issues so that i can help you properly .

**NOTE:If "Less secure app access" is turned off for your Gmail account, you have to turn it on.**  => [Click Here To see . Is it ON or OFF](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

```html
<?php 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
//Enable SMTP debug mode
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
//set PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//set host name
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
// set this true if SMTP host requires authentication to send mail
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Provide username & password
$mail->Username = "YOUR_GMAIL_EMAIL_ID";
$mail->Password = "YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;// Enter  port number 
$mail->ClearReplyTos();
$mail->addReplyTo("YOUR_GMAIL_EMAIL_ID", $_POST['name']); //$_POST['name'] => YOUR_GMAIL_NAME . You Can directly give "YOUR_GMAIL_NAME"
$mail->SetFrom("YOUR_GMAIL_EMAIL_ID", $_POST['name']);
$mail->addAddress($_POST["email"]); //TO WHOM U R SENDING MAIL
//Subject
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject =" ".$_POST['subject']." ";

$body = "<html>
           <head> </head>
                <body> 

                ".$_POST['message']." <br> 


                 </body>
            </html>";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
        if(!$mail->send()) {
            $error_message = "Mailer Error : ". $mail->ErrorInfo;
            echo $error_message;
        } else {
          echo "Email Sent Successfully";
        }

?>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)